# Select specific <option> based on the page or class I have now

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have a sidebar form on the number of pages with `<select>` dropdown in it. Each of these pages tells about a specific `option` of this dropdown. What I want to achieve is that when I am on a page about Option 1, I get Option 1 selected. When on the page about Option 2 — Option 2 is selected by default in my list. When on the page about Option 3 — Option 3 is selected by default etc. The dropdown looks like this:

```
<select>
<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

All the pages have their unique classes, that contain page ids like this `postid-2502`, so I guess I can do something like "if this class met, select this option", but is there a nicer desicion? I have ~25 options.

Also I can't change `<select>` HTML or anything as it is a plugin's dropdown. I use Contact Form 7 plugin on Wordpress website.

Comment: Is there some  consistent relationship between values or text in `<option>` and urls? Parsing url would be least amount of effort if so

Comment: What is the relationship?

Comment: @charlietfl there is no direct relationship with urls as option values are cyrillic and urls are latin..

Comment: Ok well I think the solution I provided can easily be adapted to the real page values for classes

Answer (score 1):

You could put a data attribute on each `<option>` that matches the unique post id class  or some other id source for the post and use filter() to match on page load

```js
// IIFE for wordpress to allow using $
;(function($) {  
  $('#mySelect option').filter(function() {
    return document.body.matches('.post_id_' + this.dataset['pid']);
  }).prop('selected', true);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<body class="post_id_67">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value=""> --- </option>
    <option data-pid="5" value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option data-pid="67" value="Option 2">Option 2 - Should be selected</option>
    <option data-pid="44" value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks good! I use a plugin for my form with dropdown - is there any way I can add data attributes without changing plugin's core files? Should I firstly add all "data-pid="somenumber" via js, taking these numbers from <body class="post_id_somenumber">?

Comment: Well the drawback here is you need to have a complete list of all the post_id values to start with. Typically in WP those don't change. Does the plugin create this `<select>`?

Comment: Exactly. It's the Contact Form 7 plugin with form constructor so I add this `<select>` via admin area. Pages won't be changed in the nearest future and no new pages will be added, so I guess I can get a complete list of post_id values and add them to my `<option>`s in data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

`selectElement.value = 'Option 1';` for page 1, `selectElement.value = 'Option 2';` for page 2 `selectElement.value = 'Option 3';` for page 3.